# Safest way to access data from an SQL server

Tags: php, databases

I am part of a group developing an iOS application. This app accesses a database to both retrieve and submit data. One of the group members said that he does not want to have any direct interaction with the database from the app, but for data to go through a .php on a website.

His reason for having an intermediary php page is that he does not want the database password in the code because someone could decompile the app and look at the password.

```
Friend's idea:
App -> website (.php) -> database -> website -> app
As opposed to:
App -> database -> app
```

Is this a legitimate concern? If so, is this group member's php solution effective?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please start with reading [OWASP](https://owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: Exposing a database to the internet and putting the password in an application you give to untrusted parties is a terrible idea, and the group member is right to be concerned.  Personally I wouldn't trust php  as it's long been a nighmare of security problems.

Comment: Also, the more likely route of finding your database password would be simply sniffing the connection.  No need to decompile anything when you can just find the username/password and DB URL on the wire.

Comment: Which SQL database are you asking about?  Is this regarding Microsoft SQL Server or were you using SQL server more generically (a database that uses SQL)?  The answer may be database-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is very confused. I'll assume that English is not your first language and what you are really asking is "should a DBMS be exposed on the internet?"

> he does not want the database password in the code

That's just the start of your problems.

There are things you can do to make the problem less bad than what you are currently proposing, but they still leave a **lot** to be desired.

**Use the credentials provided by the user to authenticate in the DBMS**

i.e. the database password *is* the user's password. This restricts the use of the database to known users (as opposed to making it available to anyone on the internet) and removes the need to embed the database password in the client. But it doesn't solve any of the other problems.

**restrict the accounts access to only run stored procedures**

Done properly, this would prevent an attacker from reading stuff from the database they shouldn't have access to - e.g. they should only be able to see their orders and not orders from other people. It also allows you to implement your business logic on the serverside (you can't trust logic implemented on the client). You should never store data which has not been vetted for compliance. This also gives some scope for managing the user experience more effectively when things do not proceed along the happy path. However its really hard to implement application logic in procedural SQL.

**restrict the access to specific IP addresses**

Where only known IP addresses will be accessing a service, this is good practice - it cuts down on the noise, but its not foolproof. And your mention of an IOS app (I presume you are referring to iOS, Apple's mobile device operating system, not IOS, which is Cisco's network device operating system) suggests you won't be able to determine the client address in advance.

***...but these are not nearly enough protection!!!***

DBMSs are simply not designed to be exposed in a potentially hostile environment. And SQL, using the same channel for data and control, is particularly susceptible to abuse. Nobody has been able to fix these problems on a DBMS - and indeed, nobody is trying any more as the solution is to implement a proper control layer, serverside, on top of the DBMS.

Comment: These are very good points.  The statement "nobody has been able to fix these problems" is a bit broad.  There is quite a bit you can do to secure an RDBMS.  But this depends on the specific database.  There are architectures that I would be comfortable exposing ... with the correct security protections in place.  But it would depend on the specific DB product.

Answer (score 1):

It is really confusing but the use of AJAX would meet your requirements!

1. write javascript codes then save as a `.js` file!
   In the document... write the "GET"/"POST" Method with password and user name that will connect the app to the server or to the `.php` file... that will hold actuall connection to the server!

For example:

`function obtainData(datasource){ if(window.XMLHttpRequestObject){XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET",datasource,userName,password);}...}`

2. and then use the `eval()` function to let evaluation of the fetched javascript and or php during `onreadystatechange, readystate==4 &&status==200;....`
3. This however will be saved as an external javascript document that will be included using `<script src="doc.js". . .">` which will result that when the document is viewed, the source code containing the password will be seen as .js and not the actual one!

I think the password and other info will not be prone to misuse as it will be carried in AJAX

Comment: Do you think so? I don't!